# How can I find anagrams in an array of words?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value

I am trying to get all anagrams from a array of words:

```
arr = ['cab','bac','tru']
```

The expected output is supposed to be:

```
{abc: ['cab','bac']}
```

I tried to implement the below code:

```js
var words = ['cab', 'bac', 'mihir']
let result = {}

words.forEach(word => {
  var a = word.split("").sort().join("");
  result[word] = a

})

console.log(result)
```

How do I iterate over the values so that I can access the keys if they have the same values?

Comment: Might it make more sense to use the sorted list as a key, keep a count of the number of occurances, and filter out counts <= 1? (Noting there are multiple ways this could be implemented.)

Comment: you don't need to iterate the values, but, instead of just  `result[word] = a`, you need to `if (result[word]) result[word].push(a) else result[word]=[a]`

Comment: @DaveNewton I can keep a count of the number of occurrences but how do I add it to an array which is supposed to be a value of another object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sorted words as keys in an object, and collect each word that matches the key in an array:

```
var words = ['cab', 'bac', 'mihir']
let result = {}

for (const word of words) {
  const sorted = word.split("").sort().join("");

  if (sorted in result) {
    // If there is already an entry in the result, append this word
    result[sorted].push(word);
  } else {
    // Otherwise, create one
    result[sorted] = [word];
  }
}

console.log(result);
```